# Permissions with NVidia driver on F24

Tags: linux, drivers, permissions

I'm running Fedora 24 with 4.8.4-200 kernel, and recently installed NVidia video driver 304.132 (with patch for newer kernels).

When I try to run glxinfo as a normal user (who is added to 'video' group) I get :

```
name of display: :0
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  87
  Current serial number in output stream:  88
```

Works fine when I sudo, or run this command as root. SELinux is set to be in permissive mode.

Comment: this one solved the problem for me: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321776/62276 it's for ubuntu but i assume it's only a matter of finding fedora's packages page and translating the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the Nvidia 304.132 driver, according https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/974456/f24-permission-problems-/?offset=2 .

It's also being reported at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321185/49753 and https://askubuntu.com/q/845720/227803 and many other places. Apparently the only solution at the moment is to downgrade to the previous driver version (304.131). How to do that depends on your distro.